# How to use setInterval to change opacity back and forth in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a flicker effect in React, so my down arrow can flickering , I use useEffect with setInterval to change a state from 0 to 1 , and render it with react icons, but after few tries it still not working. can anybody tell me how to achieve this effect?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const opChange = setInterval(() => {
      if (scroll) {
        scrollOpacity = 0;
        setScroll(!scroll);
      } else {
        scrollOpacity = 1;

        setScroll(!scroll);
      }
    }, 2000);
    return () => clearInterval(opChange);
  }, [scroll]);
```

```
<HiOutlineChevronDown
          className={`text-white mx-auto opacity-${scrollOpacity}`}
        />
```

tried several different method already, nothing works.

Comment: Add your Component code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use css animation to create same effect without change state.

```css
.cursor {
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

***Example:** custom cursor blink effect*

[image]